# IBM MQ performance over Secure Client

Tags: performance, ibm-mq, mq

I work on a large C++ application and often get the opportunity to continue this while at home. The IBM MQ configuration is using some kind of domain group for authentication so the application won't run unless I'm connected to the office VPN via Secure Client.

Why does the application run so much slower when connected to the VPN than in the office?

As background info, I should state the application also needs a database (Oracle) etc but all of this is locally hosted, so shouldn't be affected by the change in location.

I'm using a local MQ server as well, in case that wasn't clear.  Essentially, beyond the MQ domain authentication (which is at the start of the process as far as I can tell), application behaviour is dramatically reduced.  A process which takes 30 minutes in the office takes >2hrs at home.  I have noticed the filesystem is generally slower (although this is a SSD drive laptop).  Could Clearcase / Sophos be conflicting?

Is there a 'good way' I can monitor windows to see what exactly, if anything, is slowing the machine down out of the office?

If I get to May with no useful responses I think I'll nuke this message.  FYI, I tried server overflow as well but to no avail (they complained and said the question should live on stackoverflow instead!)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your internet speed is not very fast then that would explain the issue.

Comment: Why? Does each message need to confirm the domain authentication? This doesn't seem to.be the case. Plus my Internet is pretty speedy (fast fibre UK)